# Wordpress: frontend blocked by long running plugin script

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running Wordpress with a self-made plugin that includes a function that fetches some information from different sources. If I start that function, which often runs up to 2 minutes, the server doesn't respond to any frontend requests made - i.e. website visitors won't get a server response while the plugin function is running.

Does someone have an idea on how solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be because PHP blocks multiple requests that use the same sessions.

If your long-running script started a session, no other requests from the same user will be served until that script has either ended, or closed down the session.

If your long-running script doesn't need any session specific data, you could try running [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) at the start of the script (but after embedding the WP header files) and see whether it works any better.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. session_write_close() does exactly what I was looking for.